# Use JSON object instead of JSON file for Google API Authentication - Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, google-api, google-authentication

I'm currently using the following code to authenticate as a service account:

```js
const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
    keyFile: "<path/to/credentials>",
    scopes: [<scopes>],
});
```

Is there a way to authenticate using a JSON object containing the same content as the keyFile? For example, doing something like this:

```js
const credentials = {
  "type": ...,
  "project_id": ...,
  "private_key_id": ...,
  "private_key": ...,
  "client_email": ...,
  "client_id": ...,
  "auth_uri": ...,
  "token_uri": ...,
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": ...,
  "client_x509_cert_url": ...
}

const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
  keyFile: credentials,
  scopes: [<scopes>],
});
```

Comment: have you tried digging around in the code for the client library to see if there is an overload

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Changing `keyFile: "<path/to/credentials>",` to `credentials: credentials` did the trick as GoogleAuthOptions can also be used with a CredentialBody.

Source: [Google Cloud Node.js Docs](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/google-auth-library/latest/google-auth-library/googleauthoptions#google_auth_library_GoogleAuthOptions_credentials_member)