# How do I pass custom GoogleAuth credentials to cloud-sql-connector using environment variables

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I want to connect my Vercel hosted backend to my Google Cloud SQL instance using @google-cloud/cloud-sql-connector and service account credentials.

At the moment I can establish a connection in my local development when I set the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable to the path where the service account credentials are located.

However, I want to supersede the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS and pass in custom credentials for the service account. Vercel doesn't support filepaths so I need to add credentials from environment variables.

I have tried different options however the Connector() is not using the credentials from the GoogleAuth object and is still looking for the default credentials.

How can I get the connector to use the credentials in the GoogleAuth object?

I have tried specifying the actual JSON data (using an environment variable) in credentials as follows:

```
const connector = new Connector({
    auth: new GoogleAuth({
        credentials: process.env.CREDENTIALS_JSON,
        scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'],
      })
  });
```

and even tried specifying the path to the keyFile as follows (when testing locally):

```
 const connector = new Connector({
    auth: new GoogleAuth({
        keyFile: 'certificates/survey-engine-301112-d65599b32daa.json',
        scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'],
      }),
  });
```

However both ways still give:

Error: Could not load the default credentials

**ATTEMPT 2 - 2023-12-06**

I can create a GoogleAuth object from the service account JSON stored in environment variables ([as per this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/google-auth-library/latest#loading-credentials-from-environment-variables)) however I am trying to work out how to have the GoogleAuth.fromJSON(keys) work with cloud-sql-connector as I am still not getting a connection.

It is not throwing an error but it is not connecting either.

Here is my current code:

```
import mysql from 'mysql2/promise';
import {Connector} from '@google-cloud/cloud-sql-connector';
import {GoogleAuth} from 'google-auth-library';

let pool;

// load the environment variable with our keys
const keysEnvVar = process.env.CREDENTIALS_JSON
if (!keysEnvVar) {
  throw new Error('The CREDENTIALS_JSON environment variable was not found!');
}
const keys = JSON.parse(keysEnvVar);
console.log("keys=",keys)

const connector = new Connector({
auth: new GoogleAuth.fromJSON(keys),
});

const clientOpts = await connector.getOptions({
instanceConnectionName: 'survey-engine-301112:australia-southeast2:database-australia',
ipType: 'PUBLIC',
scope: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'],
});

if (!pool){
pool = await mysql.createPool({
...clientOpts,
user: process.env.DBUSER,
password: process.env.DBPASSWORD,
});
}

const conn = await pool.getConnection();
const [result] = await conn.query( `SELECT NOW();`);
console.table(result); // prints returned time value from server
conn.release();

export default pool
```

Here is my output from console.log("keys=",keys). I have hashed out some of the details.

```
keys= {
  type: 'service_account',
  project_id: 'survey-######-30####',
  private_key_id: 'd65############e9f',
  private_key: '-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n' +
    'MIIEvwIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBKkwggSlAgEAAoIBAQDkYpkZMXRJQfp+\n' +
    '#########################\n'+    
    'cnTc7caSvsgRFpeLCMxV5REeQw==\n' +
    '-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n',
  client_email: 'backend-to-db@survey-engine-301112.iam.gserviceaccount.com',
  client_id: '10#################22',
  auth_uri: 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth',
  token_uri: 'https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token',
  auth_provider_x509_cert_url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs',
  client_x509_cert_url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/backend-to-db%40survey-engine-301112.iam.gserviceaccount.com',
  universe_domain: 'googleapis.com'
}
```

I am using cloud-sql-connector version 1.2.0, google-auth-library version 9.2.0, mysql2 version 3.6.2 and node version 20.10.0

Comment: Can you try running [gcloud auth application-default login](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/application-default/login)? This will set Application Default Credentials to service account easily.

Comment: I want to be able to specify the credentials in the code. I have edited the question to try to clarify.

Comment: I think you are looking for this example `auth.fromJSON(keys);`: https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/google-auth-library/latest#loading-credentials-from-environment-variables When posting code, please include the library imports and versions that you are using.

Comment: @JohnHanley. Okay, I can now create a client from environment variables as per the example. How do I get the cloud-SQL-connector to use this client as credentials rather than trying to find default credentials?

Comment: The link shows you how to create an environment variable from the contents of a service account JSON file. Use the `fromJSON` function in the code that you posted. Try using the link that I provided, then modify your post with new details instead of asking via comments. That way I can see what issue you have as you solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks @JohnHanley. I have edited the question to provide more clarity.

Comment: @TerenceSweeney, Can you try importing library as `import {GoogleAuth} from 'google-auth-library'; `and wrap your credentials within `auth: new GoogleAuth(),` instead of `auth: client` as given in [this link](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-nodejs-connector#using-with-google-auth-library-nodejs-client-credentials).

Comment: 1) You will need to use the `scope` parameter otherwise you will have no permissions. 2) You replaced your previous code. I recommend instead appending to your post with a title something like `ATTEMPT 2 - 2023-12-06`. That way we can see what you started with and the changes. The comments will then make sense. 3) In your new code, we have to guess if you passed valid parameters. Show what they are.

Comment: @RoopaM. Thanks. Okay. I have tried changing to GoogleAuth however it still doesn't work for me. I have changed my code to GoogleAuth for consistency in the question. I think as per the link, I think that you should be able to provide AuthClient or GoogleAuth instance to the Connector. I am happy to work with GoogleAuth though.

Comment: @JohnHanley. Thanks. I have tried adding the scope however I am still not getting a connection. I have updated my question as per your suggestions.

Comment: Can you see these examples about how to pass files: [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72619759/18265570) & [link2](https://snyk.io/advisor/npm-package/google-auth-library/functions/google-auth-library.auth.fromJSON)

Comment: And Avoid sharing PII like Project Id, Key etc

Comment: 1) We can see each edit, so once you disclose something, it is there. 2) You have not disclosed anything harmful, just identifying information (Project PII). If you have concerns, delete the service account and create a new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below example showcases how to initialize a [Cloud SQL Node.js Connector](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-nodejs-connector) `Connector` using a custom `GoogleAuth` client from a service account key that is
[loaded into an environment variable](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/google-auth-library/latest#loading-credentials-from-environment-variables).

**Note:** Keys are expected to be loaded into env variable as a string... `export CREDS='{...}'` and not direct JSON.

```js
import {Connector} from '@google-cloud/cloud-sql-connector';
import {GoogleAuth} from 'google-auth-library';

// load the environment variable with our keys
const keysEnvVar = process.env.CREDS
if (!keysEnvVar) {
  throw new Error('The $CREDS environment variable was not found!');
}
const keys = JSON.parse(keysEnvVar);

const auth = new GoogleAuth({
    scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/sqlservice.admin']
});

const connector = new Connector({
    auth: auth.fromJSON(keys),
});
```

Comment: Thanks Jack. I want to clarify for others that the credentials first need to be turned into a string (I used JSON.parse) before placing them in an environment variable. It may be helpful to add this to your answer.

Comment: As per other recommendations, it may also be better to then base64 encode this string before placing it in the environment variable and then decoding after retrieving. This part is optional though.

Comment: Updated my answer with a note that mentions example expects env variable as string `export CREDS='{...}'`

Answer (score 1):

As per discussion in this [github](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-nodejs-connector/issues/200#issuecomment-1718352041) issue,

> Cloud SQL `Node.js` Connector uses standard `google-auth-library`, which supports `Application Default Credentials` JSON with service account impersonation.

I apologize for miscommunication in my previous answer. As you mentioned, they [implemented](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-nodejs-connector/issues/200#issuecomment-1718352041) the feature of passing custom credentials to `node.js` connecter in recent updates.

You may have a look at [this example](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/google-auth-library/latest#loading-credentials-from-environment-variables), shared by @John Hanley. If you are still unable to proceed successfully, you can raise a new issue at [`github.`](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-nodejs-connector/issues)

Comment: Custom credentials for node  connector was added as per https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-nodejs-connector/pull/238.
It is also in the documentation here https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-nodejs-connector#using-with-google-auth-library-nodejs-client-credentials
I am not sure if I am using it correctly though. Is there a more suitable place for me to post this question?

Comment: @TerenceSweeney, I have improved my answer. Can you have a look?

Comment: Thanks @Roopa. I am trying the solution in the example.